# angular "Cannot find primary outlet" when using platform-server

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

App works fine when using `platform-browser`, but doesn't work on server, throwing the following error in server console:

> ...
>
> Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'MainComponent'
>
> ...

Routing is defined in a separate module `app.routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: MainComponent,
  resolve: {
    categoryLists: CategoriesResolver
  },
  children: [
     { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [CategoriesResolver]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `children` property, then you have to have 2 router-outlets. Do you have 2 of them ? On for MainComponent, and one for its children.

In your MainComponent template, you should too have a router-outlet.

Comment: I actually have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `MainComponent` and it works fine with `platform-browser`.

Comment: so in `app.component.html` you have a `router-outlet`, and in `main.component.html` too ? Is there any `*ngIf` that could hide them by any chance ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.
No, there is no *ngIf. I'm wondering why it's not working **only with platform-server**.